# How I can run Android Studio emulator without libGL errors?

Tags: 18.04, android-studio, android-emulator

I have installed the *android-studio* snap package from the Snap Store in Ubuntu 18.04. Android Studio Emulator fails with the following errors:

```
7:17 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
7:17 PM Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
7:17 PM Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
7:17 PM Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
7:17 PM Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
7:17 PM Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
7:17 PM Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
7:17 PM Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
7:17 PM Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
7:17 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
7:17 PM Gradle build finished in 542ms
```

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating my Emulator the issue has solved.
Now it's working fine for me.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I resolved it:

1. Go to Libstdc++ dir in Android SDK directory

   [image: SDK setting]

   ```
   cd AndroidSdkDirectory/studio/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
   ```
2. Create a back up of `libstdc++.so.6`:

   ```
   mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
   ```
3. Create symbolic link to library:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6
   ```

Comment: I have not found the path "/apps/tools/android/android-sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/libstdc++" .
Note: I have installed from "Snap Store"

Comment: @AshrafuzzamanSujan that information is critical.  Make sure to include that information in your question.  (Whenever you ask a question, if you installed via a snap, via a direct download, etc. you need to let us know when asking the question)

Answer (score 0):

The Libstdc++6 bundled in the Snap package is outdated or otherwise unsuitable for this Ubuntu release. Please file a bug report with the package maintainer and use a different Android Studio installation in the mean time,

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Android Emulator 27.2.9. See the first fix listed here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#fixes